# Java - Constructor Unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have following Java configuration class which I need to unit test using JUnit:

```
public class Config {

private static final String AMQ_CONNECTION_URL_TEMPLATE = "failover:(%s)";
private final String awsAmqUrl;

public Config(String url, Optional<String> amqConnectionOptions, PropertiesManager propertiesManager) {
    String urlParameter = propertiesManager.getStringParameter(url);
    this.awsAmqUrl = constructAmqConnectionString(urlParameter, amqConnectionOptions);
}

private String constructAmqConnectionString(String urlParameter, Optional<String> connectionOptions) {
    if (connectionOptions.isPresent()) {
        urlParameter = Stream.of(urlParameter.split(","))
                .map(url -> url + "?" + connectionOptions.get())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
    return String.format(AMQ_CONNECTION_URL_TEMPLATE, urlParameter);
}

public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(awsAmqUrl);
    return connectionFactory;
}
}
```

I am struggling to find an optimal solution for `constructAmqConnectionString` method unit testing as it's marked as private.
There are 3 scenarios I am trying to cover:

- `urlParameter` - comprises comma separated URLs (url1,url2),
  `connectionOptions` is not empty;
- `urlParameter` - comprises comma
  separated URLs (url1,url2), `connectionOptions` is empty;
- `urlParameter` - comprises single URL (url1), `connectionOptions` is
  not empty.

Current solution is to add a getter into Config class for `awsAmqUrl` field so that logic of constructor's call can be verified/tested:

```
public String getAwsAmqUrl() {
    return this.awsAmqUrl;
}
```

Tests itself have following logic:

```
@Test
public void verifyConstructorWithoutMqOptionsMultiBroker() {
    when(propertiesManager.getStringParameter(any())).thenReturn("url1,url2");
    Optional<String> amqConnectionOptions = Optional.empty();
    config = new Config("url1,url2", amqConnectionOptions, propertiesManager);
    assertEquals(String.format("failover:(url1,url2)"),config.getAwsAmqUrl());
}

@Test
public void verifyConstructorWithMqOptionsMultiBroker() {
    when(propertiesManager.getStringParameter(any())).thenReturn("url1,url2");
    Optional<String> amqConnectionOptions = Optional.of("optionTest=1");
    config = new Config("url1,url2", amqConnectionOptions, propertiesManager);        
    assertEquals(String.format("failover:(url1?%1$s,url2?%1$s)",amqConnectionOptions.get()),config.getAwsAmqUrl());
}

@Test
public void verifyConstructorWithMqOptionsSingleBroker() {
    when(propertiesManager.getStringParameter(any())).thenReturn("url1");
    Optional<String> amqConnectionOptions = Optional.of("optionTest=1");
    config = new Config("url1", amqConnectionOptions, propertiesManager);                
    assertEquals(String.format("failover:(url1?%1$s)",amqConnectionOptions.get()),config.getAwsAmqUrl());
}
```

Adding a getter just for Unit testing purposes doesn't feel the right thing to do as it's breaking encapsulation.
Is there a better way to approach testing in such scenario?

Comment: Adding a getter strictly for unit testing purposes (supposing that indeed no other purpose would be served) would be an example of designing for testability.  This is a real-world design philosophy that has some traction, so there's a fair-sized cadre of people that would think it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do.  Note also that encapsulation is not an end in itself.  It is useful only insomuch as it serves other goals.

Comment: I would argue that you shouldn't unit test a constructor at all.  Your class has a purpose - which is to output `ConnectionFactory` objects.  So you should test that it outputs `ConnectionFactory` objects correctly - and although that test will use the constructor, it's not the only thing that it uses.  If you were to add a new method to the class, that outputs some other kind of object, you'd test that too.  But you'd never test the constructor in isolation, because the final state of the object is only relevant to its ability to respond correctly to the invocation of its methods, and is ...

Comment: ... not an end in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place that your class uses `awsAmqUrl` is in the `getConnectionFactory` method.  So it looks like this is the method you'll have to use, to make sure the value of `awsAmqUrl` is correct.  So instead of having a getter for `awsAmqUrl`, use something like

```
String storedUrl = objectUnderTest.getConnectionFactory().getBrokerUrl();
```

and then you can make assertions on that URL.

Sure, it makes your test dependent on the behaviour of `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` - but that's OK, since your class is tightly coupled to that particular class anyway.